# ROS2 C++ Re-Created Subscriber Not Listening

Tags: ros2, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to be able to disable a subscription temporarily, but as far as I know, the Subscription type does not support that. Rather than use `if(!disabled)` in all of my message handlers, I've taken the approach of destroying my subscriptions when they are not in use via `shared_ptr::reset()` and then calling `node::create_subscription()` again when I want to start listening.

I've been seeing a lot of cases of dropped communications, where I need to restart my C++ application to get it to start listening again, which kind of defeats the purpose of trying to do this.

I've put together a minimal test case, included below. The node subscribes to channel A and publishes every second on channel B. You can run two instances built with different topic names or run a python script to work in tandem with it, the result will be the same, as far as I can tell (I've tried both). If any command line arguments are given, then after publishing, the node has a 20% chance of resetting its subscriber and creating a new one.

Running this, against another node to publish and listen, this is what I find:

- If the subscription is never reset, either node can drop and restart and messaging continues
- If the subscription IS reset, it continues working, but only until the node publishing to it dies; if that node is started again, the subscription never reconnects

I would expect that destroying and re-creating the subscription would reconnect and continue listening as it does in the case where it's never destroyed.

So, is this an incorrect use of ROS, or is it a bug?
If I am using subscriptions incorrectly, what is the correct way to achieve the effect I want? One of the things my application does is allow users to change the topics at runtime, so if they change to topic from A to B, and then back to A, isn't that going to yield the same behavior I am seeing here?

System Details:

- Ubuntu 16.04 Kernel 4.15.0-30-generic
- ROS2 Ardent binaries installed through apt-get
- I have not set the RMW_IMPLEMENTATION environment variable, so my understanding is that FastRTPS will be used

---

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
    bool doResets = argc > 1;

    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> node = make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("pub1");

    auto publisher = node->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("world", 10);
    auto msg = make_shared<std_msgs::msg::String>();

    auto subFunc =
    [](std_msgs::msg::String::ConstSharedPtr str)
    {
        cout << "I heard: " << str->data << endl;
    };

    auto subscriber = node->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>("hello", subFunc);

    auto timer = node->create_wall_timer(1000ms,
    [&]()
    {
        cout << "Publish!" << endl;
        msg->data = "Hello World Pub3";
        publisher->publish(msg);

        if(doResets && rand() % 100 > 80)
        {
            cout << "Rebuild subscriber" << endl;
            subscriber.reset();
            subscriber = node->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>("hello", subFunc);
        }
    });

    rclcpp::spin(node);
    rclcpp::shutdown();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300339/ros2-c++-re-created-subscriber-not-listening/) by [ipiano](https://answers.ros.org/users/33331/ipiano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-08-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that this didn't appear to be an issue on the Windows side of my machine. Sure enough, specifying OpenSplice for my RMW implementation solves the problem on Linux.

However, I still don't know if this is a bug in FastRTPS or just a difference between the two that should be accounted for by using ROS differently.

---

Originally posted by [ipiano](https://answers.ros.org/users/33331/ipiano/) with karma: 35 on 2018-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-12**:
This sounds like something is not handled correctly in FastRTPS. I would suggest to report this with an issue on their tracker.

Do please link back to the issue if/when you post it over there with a comment here.

**Comment by [ipiano](https://answers.ros.org/users/33331/ipiano/) on 2018-08-12**:
Done
https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/issues/246